# How to make 2 tables on 1 page?

Tags: image, space

I want two 'menus' on my page, but when I add a `div` next to my leftmenu (where I didn't use `div` but pictures) I get ugly space between my pictures.

My current code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to Nielyboyken</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="grey">
    <br>
    <a href="http://zeldauniverse.net">
      <img src="http://i1.minus.com/jbg3tjE57KYsx1.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://i.minus.com/ip2vEndNDv7vj.png" />
    </a><text-align:"right">

    <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3qoeq8q/n48/szw135/szh135/hoc000/hbw12/hfc000/cf100/hgr0/hcw1/fas20/facfff/fdi88/mqc0033cd/mqs3/mql5/mqw2/mqd74/mhc0033cd/mhs4/mhl4/mhw2/mhd76/mmcf90/mml4/mmw1/mmd74/hhc666/hmc666" frameborder="0" width="137" height="137"></iframe>
    </font>

    <div style="width:1340px; height:20px; background-color:black;">
      <a href="contactpage.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:White;">Contact</a> 
      <a href="sign-up.html "style=text-decoration:none; color:White;"> [Register] </a> 
      <a href="log-in.html "style=text-decoration:none; color:White;">[Login]</a></font>
    </div>

    <center>
      <font style="font-family: Fixedsys;font-size: 35px;color:blue">Welcome to my  personal site!</font>
    </center>

    <center><font style="font-family:Fixedsys,;color:white">Welcome! Notice that this is not a forum site but just a personal site.</font></center>

    <div id="LeftMenu">
      <table>
        <img src="http://i5.minus.com/iI7VEHhLP3WyV.png" /> <br>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lJMgzKG1FFv2v">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/jJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" border="0"/>
        </a> 

        <div style="width:50px; height:50px; color:red;" </div> <br>

        <a href="http://zeldauniverse.net">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/ibfBWr7hEsMtsT.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="http://youtube.com">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/ib0OadHbWfnpew.png" />
        </a> <br> 

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="http://twitter.com">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/iMNcGJ5Bjwvx4.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="http://facebook.com">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/ibhDDFKmGlL4rk.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <img src="http://i4.minus.com/i6nJ7Pg8kUfqo.png" /> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="page2test.html" >
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/iFNcJv4UvSdye.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="aboutzu.html">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/ishbphpEbNRi2.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="http://twitter.com/nielyboyken">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/ihJnSHKv3vAco.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="http://www.zeldauniverse.net/forums/members/5390370-nielyboyken.html">    
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/ibdZgDlK1H5NLP.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" /> <br>

        <a href="youtube.com/nielyboyken">
          <img src="http://i.minus.com/iGZahFuxuc349.png" />
        </a> <br>

        <img src="http://i.minus.com/iJMgzKG1FFv2v.png" />

      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: you have many html-syntax errors:
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
....
</table>

perhaps you can use a wysiwyg html editor?

Comment: I suggest you write valid html first. And note that one of your div is missing a '>'. Also, try putting border="0" on your images (you can do it in css)

Comment: One problem is that `<table>` tag is not allowed to contain `<img>` or `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS. HTML is going to leave white space unless you explicitely define where you want them in your DIVs. Much easier to use a CSS template, and format with that. You will have ability to "stick" things in place with CSS.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

OR

You could use a 1x 2 table. and then insert each element inside the table. Then they would be side by side. Define Column properties, etc...

You should really Google the formatting of this stuff before you ask on here...